# Why my first Retrofit call doesn't works but the next one works perfectly?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am developing an android app using retrofit in JAVA and I am facing a problem.

When I launch my app, I launch directly a retrofit call (the one that is not working).
But when I relaunch this exact same call, this same retrofit call works perfectly.

I read about something like the first retrofit request always take more time, but I really need to resolve this issue.

Here is my call :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getLocationsOfUser")
    Call<List<LocationJson>> getLocationsOfUser(@Field("data") String data);
```

Here is my retrofit object:

```
public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://mobicampus-udl.entpe.fr/mob_stage/users/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: Please explain - what does "not work" mean?

Comment: The callbacks are not called

Comment: The question is not clear. Please [edit] the question and post [mcve] here. That means, how you're using this code in Activity or Fragment? If you tell us this, then it'd be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: _"I read about something like the first retrofit request always take more time"_ where did you read it? Can you share the link?

Comment: I don't remember where I read it but it was talking about compiling the annotation for the first time so that's normal the first request take time. I am using this in an activity